# Why the integral converges only when C is 1 and why other values of C would give infinity?

Tags: integration, limits, improper-integrals

> Find the value of the constant $C$ for which the following integral converges and evaluate the integral for this value of $C$

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{C}{x+2} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 +4}} \right]dx  = \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\int_{1}^{t}\left[\frac{C}{x+2} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 +4}} \right]dx = \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \left(\sinh^{-1}(\frac{t}{2}) - C\ln(t+2)- \text{constant}\right)$$

By taking $\ln(t+2)$ common factor
$$ \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \ln(t+2)\left(\frac{\sinh^{-1}(\frac{t}{2})}{\ln(t+2)} - C\right)- \text{constant}$$

$$ \text{Since} \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\sinh^{-1}(\frac{t}{2})}{\ln(t+2)} = 1 \text{    then C has to be equal 1} $$

and this is where I am confused
$$ \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \ln(t+2) = \infty $$

and when we multiply this by $0$, we get undefined, so why should the $C$ be $1$.
It is stated that if $C$ was anything but $1$ the answer would be  $\infty$

Comment: If $\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t)=a$ exists and $a$ is finite and if $\lim_{t\to\infty} g(t)=\infty$ it follows that $\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t)g(t)=\infty$ or $\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t)g(t)=-\infty$ right?